# Consulta SQL não funciona quando tem acentos

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho em meu banco de dados uma categoria definida como **TERRENO/ÂREAS** que ao fazer a seguinte consulta SQL não retorna nenhum resultado dos 18 existentes.

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND CATEGORIA IN ('TERRENO/ÃREAS')

Já esta consulta funciona:

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND CATEGORIA IN ('APARTAMENTO')

Algum conhecedor de **SQL** sabe porque a primeira instrução não retorna resultado? Será que é problema com caracteres?

**Atualização**

O **IN** é porque os valores obtidos são provenientes de um **array**

```
// se $tipo for um array e for maior que 0
if (is_array($tipo) && count($tipo) > 0) {
   $where .= " CATEGORIA IN ('".implode("','", $tipo)."') AND ";
} else {
   $where .= " CATEGORIA = '{$tipo}' AND ";
}
```

E é **ÃREAS** mesmo, um termo proveniente de um web service cujo software é muito mal feito e que precisa ser inserido no banco de dados dessa forma.

Comment: ÃREAS? Não seriam ÁREAS? E o IN não faz muito sentido nesse contexto, o IN serve para localizar em um set de dados. Talvez `( CATEGORIA LIKE '%TERRENO%' AND CATEGORIA LIKE '%REAS%')` fosse melhor. UPDATE baseado no edit da pergunta: Cuidado, pois se o webservice tem problema, pode ter algum caractere invisível entre o Ã e o REAS. Já tentou sanitizar os dados antes de aplicar a query?

Comment: Não tentei sanitizar !!! Isso é de comer? Desculpe a brincadeira :)

Comment: @MarcosVinicius pode ser que você precise converter de um encoding para outro, seria legal analisar o tamanho da string para ver se está com o número de caracteres que você está enxergando na tela. Muito provavelmente se você usasse uma busca binária, resolveria seu problema. Ex: Casa = 0b0001, Terreno =0b0010, Áreas = 0b0100, assim ao procurar por Terreno OU Áreas, faria um OR Binário com 0b0110, por exemplo. o MySQL tem o FIND_IN_SET para isso: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acentuação em texto literal como filtro de busca em banco de dados é um problema, pois a codificação pode ser diferente entre o aplicativo e o SGBD - você teria que garantir o sincronismo entre estas configurações.

Opções:

- Usar parâmetros em vez de concatenar o valor no comando SQL (neste caso construir dinamicamente a query usando `OR` em vez de `IN`).
- Convencionar o não uso de caracteres especiais neste campo (melhor aplicável se o campo é um identificador e não oriundo de um cadastro).

No seu caso, como o texto vem de um serviço externo e precisa tanto ser persistido quanto pesquisado, sugiro "normalizar" o texto sempre antes de persistir e antes de pesquisar.

Veja:

http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

Fazendo isso, você se protege de correções futuras que o fornecedor do serviço venha a fazer na sua codificação de strings.

Comment: Vou usar (já estou usando) a segundo opção de convencionar o não uso de caracteres especiais no campo ou até mesmo no banco de dados.